# How to run Powershell script in DockerFile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I try these below commands in dockerfile but it didnot run the script.so are there any other commands for running the ps script in dockerfile?

ADD Windowss.ps1 .

CMD powershell .\Windowss.ps1;

Answer (score 51):

To run a PS1 script file, you can do something like this:

```
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]    
RUN powershell -noexit "& ""C:\Chocolatey\lib\chocolatey.0.10.8\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1"""
```

You can also do:

```
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
WORKDIR C:\
RUN .\install_pfx.ps1
```

Comment: @shad - please accept this as the answer - it is the answer to the question you raised about how to run a powershell script from your docker file. It might not have solved your problem about running a service in a container, but that was not your question! Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can use `RUN`.

You can RUN poweshell commands using

```
RUN powershell -Command Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server
```

Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/containerized-lifecycle-architecture/design-develop-containerized-apps/set-up-windows-containers-with-powershell

Comment: How can I do this, from docker Run though?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is another command. `ENTRYPOINT ["executable", "param1", "param2"]` is a command that, according to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint), will make the container to run the executable on its start. It can be used alongside with `CMD`.

Comment: I didn't understand. You want to dockerize Windows?

Comment: Try to be clear; your first question is also not too clear. See https://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow

Comment: I just want to ask you that can we create the docker image of c# Window service?

Comment: @ravi try to do some research: https://forums.docker.com/t/dockerizing-a-windows-service-net/18415

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem which I solved by using the shell directive.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:20H2 AS PS
SHELL ["powershell"]
RUN Write-Host "Hello from docker! Today is $(Get-Date)"
```

Edit: Just noticed the answer above has a bit better of a command than mine. Upvote it! https://stackoverflow.com/a/48804143/190831

Answer (score 0):

I tried this one and it worked,

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/powershell 
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
CMD ["pwsh", "-File", "<your_powershellscript>"]
```

Here we need to mention the executable as `pwsh` not `powershell`, For your reference attaching the Github code link: [Here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docker/blob/44a656a80ea5f72bcba5de3fc31c9617ef0bd674/release/7-3/windowsserver2022/docker/Dockerfile#LL45C49-L45C49)(line: 39) [Here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docker/blob/44a656a80ea5f72bcba5de3fc31c9617ef0bd674/release/7-3/windowsserver2022/docker/Dockerfile#L56) (line: 56)