# docker RUN on windows what happens?

Tags: windows, docker, powershell

I struggle to understand what happens when `docker build` runs on windows.
Especially the `RUN` instruction.

I have seen scripts where after `RUN` instruction follows powershell code. But in my case I have to use cmd code. Is there a switch? How can I make the `RUN` run powershell?

`RUN ["powershell", ...`  causes:

'["powershell"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Is there a switch? Configuration? Flag?

Unfortunatelly the code words are kind of difficult to google due to "run" "command" and similar being kind of really general.

EDIT: (code in question)

```
ARG MINGW32_SCRIPT=install_mingw32.ps1
ARG MINGW32_INSTALLER=mingw-get-0.6.2-mingw32-beta-20131004-1-bin.zip
ADD ${MINGW32_SCRIPT} ${BASE_PATH}\\${MINGW32_SCRIPT} 
COPY ${MINGW32_INSTALLER} ${BASE_PATH}\\${MINGW32_INSTALLER}

RUN powershell -command "%BASE_PATH%\%MINGW32_SCRIPT%"
```

This is what I have now, this works. But the return value of the script is ignored. (As powershell returns sucessfully.)

I want the last line to be something like:

```
RUN ${BASE_PATH}\\${MINGW32_INSTALLER}
```

I want the build to fail when the script fails. But this fails. (As for some reason after RUN I have to post CMD code. It calls cmd, that calls powershell.

If it matters, the win is server 2016.

Thanks for help
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Can you try any of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47131545/how-to-run-powershell-script-in-dockerfile) and check if that helps.

Comment: You can change the default shell in your Dockerfile to Powershell by saying `SHELL ["powershell", "-command"]`. After that, all `RUN` commands will be sent to Powershell, so you can do `RUN Write-Host hello` for instance. It requires that Powershell is installed in the image though.

Comment: @HansKilian Thank you, that is what I was looking for!